# PHP object inside other object

Tags: php, object

I have an object `$user`.

`var_dump($user)` will output this:

```
object(user)#12 (1) {
  ["mylog"]=> object(mylog)#13 (2) { 
    ["userid"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["uname"]=> string(5) "admin"
  }
}
```

What I want to access is the "userid" property. I succeeded with

```
foreach($user as $otherObject=>$property)
{
     echo $property->userid;
}
```

My question is if I can do something like `$user->OtherObjectPlaceholder->userid` without needing to loop through all the properties?

Comment: ... $user->mylog->userid

Answer (score 2):

You can make chaining at php for methods if you return object. This is called [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

```
class a
{
  public $a;

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->a = new b; 
  }
}

class b {
   public $b;
}

$object = new a;
$object->a->b
```

Answer (score 0):

create a getter in $user object and run this:

```
$user->getOtherObject()->userid
```

Comment: could you explain in more detail, I'm new to oop, how can I create a getter inside the object I already have?